# Creating a group identifying variable with case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, case-when

I have a dataset of individuals part of bigger families, so there is a variable that identifies the respondent's relationship to the head of the household who was interviewed (parent, child, brother, etc).

I want to create a variable that identifies their "generation group". 
My groups are:

```
gen0 <- c("grandparent", "grandparent_ofwife")
gen1 <- c("parent", "parent_inlaw", "parent_ofcohab")
gen2 <- c("head", "wife_legal", "wife_cohabit", "husband_legal", "y1_cohab")
gen3 <- c("child", "child_step", "child_ofwife", "child_inlaw", "child_foster", "child_1y_cohab")
```

I've tried using case_when to create a new "generation" variable with this code:

```
dat2<- dat %>% mutate('2017_generation' = case_when('2017_relation_head' %in% gen0 ~ "gen0",
                                                 '2017_relation_head' %in% gen1 ~ "gen1",
                                                 '2017_relation_head' %in% gen2 ~ "gen2",
                                                 '2017_relation_head' %in% gen3 ~ "gen3"))
```

But the new variable "2017_generation" is still filled completely with NA values. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? (sample data below)

```
id  2017_relation_head
1   wife_legal
2   head
3   wife_legal
4   head
5   wife_legal
6   head
7   wife_legal
8   child
9   child
10  NA
11  child
12  child
13  child
14  child
15  child
16  head
17  parent
18  NA
19  grandchild
20  child_step
```

Comment: Instead of single quotes (`'`) use backquotes to reference column name. (`\``).

Comment: Ah yes, that was it, silly mistake on my part! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. I think the main problem was the quotes around the variable name. But, also, the name of the column can't start with a number.

```
gen1 <- c("parent", "parent_inlaw", "parent_ofcohab")
gen2 <- c("head", "wife_legal", "wife_cohabit", "husband_legal", "y1_cohab")
gen3 <- c("child", "child_step", "child_ofwife", "child_inlaw", "child_foster", "child_1y_cohab")
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame("x2017_relation_head" = sample(c(gen0, gen1, gen2, gen3),
                                                size = 100, replace = TRUE))
dat$x2017_relation_head <- as.character(dat$x2017_relation_head)
dat2<- dat %>% mutate(genx = 
          case_when(x2017_relation_head %in% gen0 ~ "gen0",
            x2017_relation_head %in% gen1 ~ "gen1",
            x2017_relation_head %in% gen2 ~ "gen2",
            x2017_relation_head %in% gen3 ~ "gen3"))
head(dat2)
  x2017_relation_head genx
1      child_1y_cohab gen3
2         child_inlaw gen3
3          child_step gen3
4       husband_legal gen2
5          child_step gen3
6         child_inlaw gen3
```